# Combine query and named query in HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on Spring MVC, Spring Data and Hibernate.

I have an entity like this:

**FAQ**

```
@Entity
public class Faq extends CAccountOwner implements Serializable{
     @OneToOne
     @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
     private DynamicText question;
}
```

**DynamicText**

```
@Entity
public class DynamicText implements Serializable {

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Locale, LocalizedDynamicText> localized = new HashMap<Locale, LocalizedDynamicText>();

    public DynamicText() {
    }

    @CollectionTable(name = "localized_dynamic_text")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "dynamic_text_for_locale")
    public Map<Locale, LocalizedDynamicText> getLocalized() {
        return this.localized;
    }
}
```

(I've passed only the significant par of the class)

I've created a query to get all the *faqs* that have a *question* in locale "EN".

```
select f from Faq f where 'EN' in indices(f.question.localized)
```

So, by *indices* function return the list of the key from the *localized* map.

The query is working, but each time I have a **DynamicText** in a entity, I have to produce that part of the query:

```
where 'EN' in indices(f.myDynamicText.localized)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid to write each time that part and replace it by a call on a specific function of the DynamicText entity like

```
where f.myDynamicText.fromLocale('EN')
```

?

In other words, Calling a named query within another query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some more details. Right now there is a good portion of imagination needed to understand what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Is it clearer like this?